# iTunes music available from iPad iTunes to iPhone iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, ios

I used iPad 2 a long time before getting iPhone 4S so all my music is on there. Now I cannot get the music from iPad to iPhone. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your country, more [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4539). For me, it is not possible without OSx and iTunes.

[image]

If you have iPad and iPhone in less-supported country, you can make your life million-times easier if you buy some OSx -device such as laptop or old desktop. I really-really hate this feature but in order to use iOS -devices well, you should really consider investing in OSx.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you got the music from.

- If you purchased it through iTunes on your iPad, then you can open iTunes on your phone, select the **"More"** tab, then tap **"Purchased"**, then download the music onto your phone. "Purchased" is an iCloud feature. iCloud must be enabled, and configured correctly on all your iOS 5 or later devices. The navigation in getting to Purchase history has changed slightly, I believe, between iOS 5 and iOS 6, but the idea is the same.
- If you ripped CDs, then transferred the content over to your iPad, you will have to use the computer that you ripped them to to sync the songs onto the iPhone.
- If you downloaded them from somewhere such as Amazon on your computer before transferring them to your iPad, then you will need to connect your iPhone to your computer to sync those purchases.

One thing to note: you cannot transfer songs *from* your iPad *to* your computer with iTunes (unless it was purchased from iTunes, and the computer is authorized). So, in other words, if you no longer have the computer that had all your songs on it, and just your iPad does, you will want to look for third party software ([maybe like this?](http://www.copytrans.net/) I haven't used it, but just did a Google search) to transfer your media to your computer, then to your phone.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot find "Purchased" -tab. I have bought all music from iTunes in iPad but cannot understand how to get the music from iPad to iPhone still. It can see what I have listened from history but it looks like I need pay twice for the same music?!

Comment: You certainly do not need to purchase all your music again. Have you looked in the iTunes app on your iPhone for the Purchased tab? It should be the 4th from the left.

Comment: I'm am sorry. That was indeed my bad. That is something that I believe was changed in iOS 6. Tap the "More" tab all the way to the right. When in there, you will see the "Purchased" link in the table view. Again, I am sorry about that. Hopefully that works for you. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Ok. It is in there in my iTunes (iOS 6). So you have something weird going on. First check the downloads, that were pictured. I don't think what you want will be in there, but it's worth double checking. Second, I would check Settings > iTunes & App Stores, and make sure that you have the correct (the one you used to purchased your music on your iPad) Apple ID in there. You could also try purchasing one song on your iPhone to see if the Purchased link appears. Lastly, I believe this is a feature of iCloud. You may need to enable iCloud to re-download the music.

Comment: Sorry but this contains old-dated info hence -1. I got things working when I connected iPhone and iPad into OSx. I could not find any other way to get musics between iOS devices without second-time-buying everything. I feel a bit painful in downvoting you but hence clarified question, could you separate ios5 things from ios6? If you do it, I will move my downvote into upvote.

Comment: I re-read my answer and confirmed that there is indeed nothing that would change between iOS 5 and iOS 6 (except for minor navigation differences on getting to "Purchased"). Being able to retrieve content on *any* iOS device signed into your Apple ID, *without* using OSX is entirely an iCloud service - something introduced in iOS 5 on compatible devices. They have not removed this feature in iOS 6, and, if anything have improved it. Your new answer would be correct with *iOS 4* (but still works with iOS 5 and 6). Keep in mind, at the time of writing, you never specified which iOS you were on.

Comment: Here is some information that might help. http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/itunes-in-the-cloud/ Scroll to the bottom of the page for information on how to configure this, if it is available in your country.

Comment: Huh? Downvote for an accurate answer to a non-specific question?